# Change notifications in Realm for inner objects?

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

When I have an object `A` that contains a realm-list of `B`, if I have a query for a specific A and edit an item in its `B` list; I wont receive a change notification

Is this the desired behavior?

Code sample:

```
class ExerciseInfo : RealmObject() {
    @PrimaryKey 
    var id: String? = null
    var muscleFields: MuscleFields? = null
}

class MuscleFields : RealmObject() {
    var muscles: RealmList<Muscle>? = null
}

class Muscle : RealmObject() {
    var id: String? = null
    var name: String? = null
}

//Example, performed inside a Realm transaction
realm.where(ExerciseInfo::class.java)
    .findFirst()
    .muscleFields
    ?.muscles
    ?.let{ it.first().name += ":)" }
```

All of the above is sample code - but the scenario is exactly the same.

I can verify that the edit is performed and stored in the database; and that no change notification is triggered for the ExeciseInfo RealmObject, regardless of whether Im using it with a addChangeListener() or the Flowable method. Moreover, the same scenario **does work if the edit being made is performed directly on the exercise class, e.g. editing some fields directly on the ExerciseInfo class, and not another object inside it.**

I hope that makes sense. Thought Id post this on SO before the Realm Github as it may be something Ive missed, and not a bug.

Any idea? - Let me know. Thanks!

Comment: What is the `RealmChangeListener` added to?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce The ExerciseInfo object.

Comment: Like, `exerciseInfo.addChangeListener(new RealmObjectChangeListener` or something like that? Not the `realmResults`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce In this case Im just querying one object (findFirst()) so the listener is added directly to it.

Comment: It should be the desired behavior. See https://realm.io/docs/java/4.2.0/api/io/realm/RealmObject.html#addChangeListener-io.realm.RealmObjectChangeListener- It should be triggered if you add/remove/move element in the List, but not modify object in the list.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce realm expert :D. i do expect your answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505171/android-realm-database-decryption-failed

Answer (score 0):

`RealmChangeListener` added to objects directly will *not* be notified for changes in the list (link field).

For that, you need to add the listener to a `RealmResults<T>`.

Comment: If I query for a list, Id like to get notified if any of the items are modified (updated or removed) as well as if any new items are added. For a single item, Id just like to know if it gets updated or removed. This works for the most part, but not if I update an items inner fields (as in my example above).

Comment: Single-object notifications don't notify for linked objects. For that, you'd need a `RealmResults<T>` of your single object (which is what I tend to recommend unless you are listening for specific field changes) which can be done with `equalTo("id", id)` condition. This way it is also resilient against item deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in your activity

```
class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  RealmChangeListener<Realm> {


onCreate(...){

realm.addChangeListener(this);// make sure you init realm transaction

}

     @Override
    public void onChange(@NonNull Realm realm) {
    // this method will be call after any change in realm
    }
}
```

*Don't forget to remove all registered listeners in `onDestroy` method.*

---

**OR**

```
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

realm.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<Realm>() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(Realm realm) {
                // do something 
            }
        });
```